# How change the drupal default css of a custom theme?

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm working on a site locally in which I use the Mayo forest theme. I'm trying to customize this theme through the css/style.css file, which works mostly. But some things I find are to change in another directory like sites/default/files/ . Here I can find the css lines to change, but once I clear the site's cache, the changes are undone. The changes mostly include removing background colors and spaces. Can anyone tell me how to get this done properly, whitout loosing it after caching?

for example when I want to change or delete the background-color of the sidebar I find it is stored in sites/default/files/color/mayo-56cb6ab4/colors.css. Only when I delete it in there the markup of style.css starts to work, otherwise it just gets overwritten. But once I clear the cache this directory gets rewritten with a new default colors.css file. So how to make sure that the changes stay put?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must go to:

```
 sites/all/themes/mayo/css
```

in this folder you can see all the css files for the theme mayo, usually you can find the css that you need change in the `style.css` file

When you need modifiy the css of a custom theme (not core theme) you must go to:

```
 sites/all/themes/MY_CUSTOM_THEME/css
```

I suppose that you place your custom themes in the folder:

```
 sites/all/themes/
```

as the Drupal manual says.

Comment: Yes I know this, but some properties of the css are not stored there and when I try to change them in mayo/css/style.css they get overwritten by other default files. I already tried deleting these lines, but like said when I clear the cache the directory of these default files get overwritten to original.

Comment: @boselfje tell me which one, and edit your question with an example

Answer (score 0):

According to the [project documentation](https://www.drupal.org/project/mayo), MAYO is using the theme settings to configure some properties (for instance the colors). Based on your description, it seems that the theme manages internally some CSS files (by creating them dynamically on sites/default/files).

A possible workaround might be to create a sub-theme and add your own CSS to overwrite the defaults. There seems to be some documentation about it here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2261457

Hope that helps,